# The GNOME Terminal is very slow in GNOME 3

Tags: 11.10, command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

When using the GNOME Terminal, if I try to create a new tab, or use "C+tab" to cycle to a new one, the terminal will take up to five full seconds to change. This seems to occur whether using ZSH or Bash. Has anyone run into this issue? Or, does anyone know how to get debugging information from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not experienced this issue.
You may want to try an alternative terminal emulator such as `xterm` or `uxterm`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#X_Window_Terminals

Comment: Is there anything that compares X Window Terminals? I definitely will scroll up in Gnome-Terminal, and I use a transparent background so I can read documentation while typing in the window.

Comment: So I ended up settling with Terminator. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I have the exact same problem.  It doesn't happen all the time, but it does happen a majority of the time and I hate it.  Also, text prints very slowly in the terminal.  So if I print out a large number of characters, the terminal spits it out in jumps and increments.  It's very laggy.  This is a major issue.

UPDATE: I press alt-f2, then hit "r" to reset Gnome.  Your session remains intact, but it reboots Gnome, and then my terminals work very nicely...so this is a memory leak or bug in Gnome.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  It may not be a solution, but it's a great workaround.

Comment: has that bug been reported? I'm still bitten by this in march 2013.

Answer (score 4):

Do you use NVIDIA drivers? Then you might be affected an bug in the driver. The new [295.20 release](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-295.20-driver.html) states a potential fix:

> Fixed a bug that could cause some OpenGL applications (including desktop environments like KDE and GNOME Shell) to hang.

EDIT: An more in-depth discussion if found at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/78237/unity-3d-with-nvidia-driver-becomes-very-slow-and-laggy

Comment: I do use nvidia drivers fwiw.  The answer you link to was removed unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed I also notice it being something of Nvidia. On my other system (which has AMD graphics) I see no slowness.

Answer (score 2):

I have found terminator, my favorite term, has the same problem creating or switching tabs. It makes Gnome 3 unusable. I usually have somewhere in the range of 4 or 5 tabs of console open with each one possibly split many times. Sometimes creating new tabs causes the entire Gnome 3 UI to freeze, and the only way to get back in is restart gdm from one of the actual consoles (ctrl+alt+f1)

Answer (score 1):

`GNOME terminal` is also slow for me. From the Wikipedia list the fastest of what I tested was `evilvte`. That one seems to go all the way to the opposite end of the spectrum in terms of leaving out as many features as possible. (Whereas I sense that `GNOME terminal` chooses to be quite featureful.)

The other fast alternative for me is to use the virtual terminal. If you hit any of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> you will get a minimal, quick console interface. Striking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> returns you to the usual graphical interface with windows and such.

Combining those virtual terminals with `tmux` (a `GNU screen` replacement) has been helpful for me. In `tmux` it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to open a new window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> to split the screen into two frames, each with its own terminal interface, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to close a frame.